# How can I group Saturday/Sunday rows as "Weekend" with dates given in SMALLDATETIME?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of dates I am trying to group by weekday, however I would like to group the Saturday/Sunday rows as "Weekend".

```
SELECT DATENAME(weekday, [MYDATE])
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY DATENAME(weekday, [MYDATE])
```

The results group by weekday, but Saturday/Sunday are their own rows. I have no idea how to group these two rows together. I can't change the formatting from SMALLDATETIME nor can I alter the tables.

Comment: you could first make a classification with CASE for example, case saturday/sunday return just Weekend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach, but not necessary the fastest performance, so consider if table is small.

```
SELECT DATENAME(weekday, [MYDATE])
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) IN (2,3,4,5,6)
GROUP BY DATENAME(weekday, [MYDATE])
UNION ALL
SELECT 'WEEKEND'
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) IN (1,7)
GROUP BY DATENAME(weekday, [MYDATE])
```

You can also use the CASE statement as p Waksman suggested.   If the table is large, I would suggest that approach since it will likely perform better than the UNION syntax